# python usb keyboard unplugged

Tags: python, pyusb

My eventual goal is to detect if a usb keyboard is unplugged - it has to work on mac, windows and linux, which is why I went for python.  (basically I have a switching usb hub, like a kvm - but only the usb - and I want to do certain things like shut off the screen when you switch away from a box; I have mac, windows and linux boxes on the switch).

I saw the pyusb and thought, ok - I'll use that to poll usb devices every 30s or so.   so

I started with windows - did the following

- `pip install pyusb`
- `pip install libusb`
- `copy C:\python39\lib\sitepackages\libusb\_platform_windows\x64\libusb-1.0.dll C:\python39\scripts`

and then tried the following script in jupyter

```py
import usb
for bus in usb.busses():
    for device in bus.devices():
            print( "Device: " + device.filename )
```

and it just dies on the first line with "entity not found".
any idea how to fix this?
Or otherwise how to get an event when a usb keyboard (or other device) is disconnected?

Comment: I'm on MacOS and I simply get: `usb.core.NoBackendError: No backend available`

Comment: I got the nobackend available - googled -a nd it appears you need the libusb dll in the path - that's why I did the copy above - so that fixed that problem... and moved me onto the next :)

Comment: According to https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/issues/120 on MacOS you need to `brew install libusb` first.
Which worked indeed

Comment: You have an error in your Python code: it must be `python.devices`

Comment: yeah - I don't get to there - the program dies on the "usb.busses" line - with "entity not found"

Comment: Seems relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458303/pyusb-error-usberror-errno-2-entity-not-found-using-libusb0-driver-windows

Comment: And this too https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/issues/186

Answer (score 0):

I edited your Python snippet to provide more information (tested on Mac OS):

```py
import usb
for bus in usb.busses():
    print(f"bus: {bus.location}")
    print(f"Device count: {len(bus.devices)}")
    for device in bus.devices:
            print(f"Device: {device.__dict__}")
    print()
```

Whit this script I get an additional entry if I plug a keyboard into the USB Hub.

Comment: but my program fails on the "usb.busses" - so it doesn't make any difference what I put inside the loop