# `pyusb` fails to find `libusb` when using `pyinstaller`

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, pyusb, libusb-1.0

## Problem

My application works well when in python-only and on my machine.  I am attempting to deploy to a machine which has lesser privileges.

The basic script that I am attempting to run at the moment:

```py
import logging

import os
os.environ['PYUSB_DEBUG'] = 'debug'
os.environ['PYUSB_LOG_FILENAME'] = 'C:\\path\to\log.txt'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

import usb.core
import usb.util

devices = [d for d in usb.core.find(find_all=True,
                                    idVendor=0x0683,
                                    idProduct=0x2008
                                    )]

[print(d) for d in devices]

device = devices[0]
device.set_configuration()
```

The imports are a bit out of whack in this example file because the `os.environ` variable must be set before `usb` import or the logging won't be set up properly to get my `log.txt` from the `usb` module.

### From Python

When I execute the above script on my machine, this is the resulting `log.txt`:

```
2022-05-13 06:50:02,760 DEBUG:usb.backend.libusb1:_LibUSB.__init__(<WinDLL 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\libusb-1.0.dll', handle 7ff8476e0000 at 0x20a622c18b0>)
2022-05-13 06:50:02,760 DEBUG:usb.backend.libusb1:_LibUSB.__init__(<WinDLL 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\libusb-1.0.dll', handle 7ff8476e0000 at 0x20a622c18b0>)
2022-05-13 06:50:02,766 INFO:usb.core:find(): using backend "usb.backend.libusb1"
2022-05-13 06:50:02,766 INFO:usb.core:find(): using backend "usb.backend.libusb1"
2022-05-13 06:50:02,767 DEBUG:usb.backend.libusb1:_LibUSB.enumerate_devices()
...
...(more logs past this point, but you can see that the core found the backend)
```

### From `pyinstaller` executable

I am bundling using pyinstaller.  I normally like to use `--onefile`, but I always verify functionality without `--onefile`.  I am only doing the most basic build: `pyinstaller --noconfirm path/to/script.py`

The console error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "usb\backend\libusb0.py", line 738, in get_backend
  File "Lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_usb.py", line 57, in _load_libraryOSError: USB library could not be found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "backend_test.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "usb\core.py", line 1309, in find
usb.core.NoBackendError: No backend available
[9344] Failed to execute script backend_test
```

Note that the USB library failed to find a `backend`.

The fail `log.txt` when attempted to run the executable:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "usb\backend\libusb0.py", line 738, in get_backend
  File "Lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_usb.py", line 57, in _load_library
OSError: USB library could not be found
2022-05-13 06:20:59,838 ERROR:usb.backend.libusb1:Error loading libusb 1.0 backend
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 961, in get_backend
  File "Lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_usb.py", line 57, in _load_library
OSError: USB library could not be found
2022-05-13 06:20:59,840 ERROR:usb.backend.openusb:Error loading OpenUSB backend
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "usb\backend\openusb.py", line 745, in get_backend
  File "Lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_usb.py", line 57, in _load_library
OSError: USB library could not be found
2022-05-13 06:20:59,842 ERROR:usb.backend.libusb0:Error loading libusb 0.1 backend
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "usb\backend\libusb0.py", line 738, in get_backend
  File "Lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_usb.py", line 57, in _load_library
OSError: USB library could not be found
```

At the moment, I can tell that the failure is occurring in a [pyinstaller hook](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller-hooks-contrib).  I don't understand precisely how this works, so the clue may be found somewhere in there.

## Background & Research

### Versioning

```
libusb==1.0.24b3
pyinstaller==4.3
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2022.4
pyusb==1.2.1
... (there is more, but I suspect that these are the critical-to-function packages)
```

### `libusb`

Not sure why this installed the beta version.  Interesting, but doesn't appear to be the smoking gun.

### `pyinstaller`

Note that `pyinstaller==4.3` is a bit out of date.  This is a result of my overambitious IT department's antivirus.  It doesn't appear to want to allow more recent versions of pyinstaller to build executables.

### `pyinstaller-hooks-contrib`

This is a repository which contains several `pyinstaller` hooks.  I know that these are "critical to function" for lots of modules, but I don't really know how this works.  It is possible, even likely given that this is where something is failing, that my problem lies within this library OR with this library's interaction with the version of `pyinstaller` that I'm using.  Version `2022.4` is the version that is installed when I `python -m pip install pyinstaller`.

### `pyusb`

Current version.

## Other Attempts Thus Far

I have been up and down the web and have spent a particularly long time with the SO question [Pyusb on windows - no backend available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773132/pyusb-on-windows-no-backend-available).  Many of the below attempts were based on that SO question, but there have been other sources as well.

There are more attempts than just these, but I have been at it long enough that I don't remember them all!

### Bundling `libusb-1.0.dll` into Executable

It is possible to bundle `dll` files directly with the `pyinstaller`-created script using the `datas` directive.  This was my first attempt and it worked... on my machine.  As soon as I deployed, the script failed with a `PermissionError`.  I suspect that "untrusted" dll's aren't allowed to be utilized on the target machine.  My login on my machine has elevated privileges, explaining why it may have worked in my environment.

### Installing `libusb-win32-devel-filter.exe`.

Simply didn't work.

### Including `C:\\Windows\\System32` on `PATH`

I verified that the `PATH` variable contained `C:\\Windows\\System32`, which I also verified contains the proper `dll` file.

### Specify backend

When I modify the script to specify the backend:

```
...
import usb.backend.libusb1 as libusb1

be = libusb1.get_backend(find_library=lambda x: "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\libusb-1.0.dll")
devices = [d for d in usb.core.find(find_all=True,
                                    idVendor=0x0683,
                                    idProduct=0x2008,
                                    backend=be)]
...
```

There is no change in behavior.  I do see in the log when running in python (not pyinstaller) that the backend is immediately found:

```
2022-05-13 07:22:12 USBN1LPGDKWXD3 usb.backend.libusb1[6880] DEBUG _LibUSB.__init__(<WinDLL 'C:\Windows\System32\libusb-1.0.dll', handle 7ff840bd0000 at 0x190eadbe820>)
2022-05-13 07:22:12 USBN1LPGDKWXD3 usb.backend.libusb1[6880] DEBUG _LibUSB.enumerate_devices()
2022-05-13 07:22:12 USBN1LPGDKWXD3 usb.backend.libusb1[6880] DEBUG _LibUSB.get_device_descriptor(<usb.backend.libusb1._Device object at 0x00000190EAE58EB0>)
2022-05-13 07:22:12 USBN1LPGDKWXD3 usb.backend.libusb1[6880] DEBUG _LibUSB.get_device_descriptor(<usb.backend.libusb1._Device object at 0x00000190EAE58F40>)
...
```

### Install `libusb`

No change.

### Modify `pyinstaller` and `pyinstaller-hooks-contrib` versions

Tried `pyinstaller==4.10` and `python-hooks-contrib==2022.3`, which appear to be "compatible" releases.

I would like to try to build the pyinstaller script by excluding the `pyusb` from `pyinstaller-hooks-contrib`, but I'm not sure how to do this.

## Other Clues....

While looking in `pyinstaller-hooks-contrib`, I'm seeing the way to access DLL files is through `ctypes.WinDLL`.

```
import ctypes

print('ctypes.WinDLL', ctypes.WinDLL('libusb-1.0.dll'))
```

Result when running from python: `<WinDLL 'libusb-1.0.dll', handle 7ff831cc0000 at 0x21076e9adf0>`
Result when running from pyinstaller: `ctypes.WinDLL <PyInstallerWinDLL 'libusb-1.0.dll', handle 7ff83d400000 at 0x201a9f39fa0>`

Answer (score 2):

I'm still not sure why this works the way that it does, but my initial instincts were correct when I had tried to include `libusb-1.0.dll` in the pyinstaller package.  Unfortunately, there is apparently an issue with the windows implementation of the `libusb-1.0.dll` (I'm not making that assertion, I'm quoting [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67402622/3037766)).

The answer, for me, was to add `libusb0.dll` to my pyinstaller build directory instead of the more recent `libusb-1.0.dll`:

```
a = Analysis(['examples\\backend_test.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('C:\\Windows\\System32\\libusb0.dll', '.'),],
             hiddenimports=[],
             ...])
```

I can't believe that it was this simple in my case, but there it is...

Comment: I tried many ways , yours is the only one that works for me!